# My scss loop only goes to 1vw rather than 100vw spread over 12

Tags: sass

I'm trying to loop through twelve margin-top classes in scss; from 0vw to 100vw spread over 12, but mine only goes to 1vw.

Maths really is not my strong suit.

Would be grateful for some help, please.

```
$grid-heights: 12;

@for $i from 1 through $grid-heights {
    .u-marg-t-vw#{$i}of12 {
        margin-top: ($i / $grid-columns) + vw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$i / $grid-columns` would be `1 / 12` to `12 / 12` in your loop.

Assuming you want an even distribution, you're looking to simply multiply this by 100:

```
$grid-heights: 12;

@for $i from 1 through $grid-heights {
    .u-marg-t-vw#{$i}of12 {
        margin-top: ($i/12 * 100)vw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My mistake, needs a `+ vw` on the end. Thanks so much.